# Getting InvalidSignatureException error whereas my time on the machine is correct

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, terraform

terraform apply gives me the following error:

Error: Error creating Lambda function: InvalidSignatureException: Signature expired: 20190628T091524Z is now earlier than 20190628T092024Z (20190628T092524Z - 5 min.)

Many have recommended to fix the time on the local machine from where i am running the terraform command, but that seems not the problem for me. My local machine time is correct, no issues there.

This one did not solve my problem :( [Terraform apply failed due to mismatch time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53740432/terraform-apply-failed-due-to-mismatch-time)

Comment: What happens if you run an AWS CLI command instead? How are you running Terraform? Directly with the binary or in a Docker container? Is this happening locally or on another machine or in a VM?

Comment: I did not try it from AWS CLI. I am running is directly from the binary (version 0.12.3) on my local machine (no docker, no VM).

Comment: What's stopping you from running an AWS CLI command? Something like `aws sts get-caller-identity` should be fine

Comment: Did not find any issue on running the command you mentioned.

Comment: Is it the speed issue as mentioned at:
https://github.com/apex/apex/issues/632

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I Think its happen due to slow internet issue, So I fix this by following steps.

- install NPM module on the fly
- create zip on the fly
- push zip to s3
- then specify the target key from s3 instead of pushing zip from local

Here is the working code.

```
 resource "null_resource" "npm" {
      provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "cd ../lambda-functions/loadbalancer-to-es && npm install --prod=only && chmod -R 777 node_modules"
      }
    }

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "file_upload" {
  bucket = "${var.env_prefix_name}${var.s3_suffix}"
  key    = "lambda-functions/loadbalancer-to-es.zip"
  source = "${data.archive_file.source.output_path}"
  # etag   = "${filemd5("../lambda-functions/loadbalancer-to-es.zip")}"
}

# Zip the Lambda function on the fly
data "archive_file" "source" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "../lambda-functions/loadbalancer-to-es"
  output_path = "../lambda-functions/loadbalancer-to-es.zip"
  depends_on  = ["null_resource.npm"]
}


# Created AWS Lamdba Function: Memory Size, NodeJS version, handler, endpoint, doctype and environment settings
resource "aws_lambda_function" "elb_logs_to_elasticsearch" {
  function_name = "${var.env_prefix_name}-alb-logs-to-elk-test"
  s3_bucket = "${var.env_prefix_name}${var.s3_suffix}"
  s3_key    = "${aws_s3_bucket_object.file_upload.key}"
  description   = "elb-logs-to-elasticsearch"
  memory_size   = 1024
  timeout       = 900
  runtime       = "nodejs8.10"
  role          = "${aws_iam_role.role.arn}"
  depends_on  = ["null_resource.npm" ]
  source_code_hash = "${base64sha256(data.archive_file.source.output_path)}"
  handler       = "index.handler"


  environment {
    variables = {
      ELK_DOCKTYPE = "some env"
    }
  }
}
```